# How to Convert Date with ZZZ

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm want to query for an object in my CoreData using NSDate.

I have an string like "2013:32:17 **06**:32:24 **-0300**".

When I get the object and convert it using "[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss ZZZ"]" I get a string like "2013:32:17 **09**:32:24 **+0000**"

How do I convert to the same original format above (-0300 ???) 
Tk's!!

Comment: To convert to the original format you use the date formatter to create a string from the date object.  NSLog will always dump an NSDate object in the form you're showing, and in GMT, and this is not a bug.

Comment: tk's hot licks. But that's what I wan't to know, what kind of "HH:mm:yy ..."(dateFormatter) I need to make a string equals to the original string using this NSDate..

Comment: You already have it (sort of).  Just run it backwards -- stringFromDate instead of dateFromString.  Your above format is slightly defective -- should be `yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ`.  See the [date format patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).